# Query a gmail inbox through the API

Tags: java, email, gmail-api

I know this is a pretty noob question but I've been reading some manuals and documentations and can't figure something out.

I have an automation suite (in Java/Groovy) that in some cases needs to query an email inbox to check that a message with a given subject has been received and also probably delete all messages older than X. That's pretty much all I need to do and I've been looking into creating a gmail account and using the Google API Java client that's available here -> https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/gmail/v1 but I can't figure our how to actually do it.

Right now what I have absolutely no clue how to do is the authentication. I can probably figure out how to interact with emails by going through the methods/code but I can't find any examples on how to authenticate so that the code can get access. 
I tried looking for examples [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/samples) and checking the code [here](https://github.com/google/mail-importer/tree/master/src/main/java/to/lean/tools/gmail/importer/gmail). I know the answer is there but I still can't wrap my head around how to implement the code to sign in/authorize based on a username and password.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2) is the link you need. In this page it's explained authentication mechanism for Google API. They are using [OAuth 2.0](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/), which is probably the most used authentication method nowdays.

There is a standard flow that takes the client from credentials to an access token that can be used to perform authorised requests. This flow is described in the [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/) specification which is very useful to understand. Many APIs use it.

If you have specific questions, please let us know.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me understand things a bit more. I'm struggling now to get the access token from the code. I think I should be using the class `GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest` or `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` but can't figure out how to do it.